# Azure App Center - error `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin). Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, visual-studio-app-center

When building react native app on App center getting the following error in the console, this is only when in release mode, not debug

```
warning: the transform cache was reset.
error `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin). Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 28s
68 actionable tasks: 62 executed, 6 up-to-date
Error: /Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:509:12)
##[error]Error: /Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1
##[section]Finishing: Gradle Task
```

The same build command used by app center works locally, though I am on windows and I don't know if app center is running a linux shell.
Any help anyone can give me would be great

Comment: Running the same command on a mac locally we were able to resolve the issue by running, brew reinstall watchman, but not sure how to run this on app center